# Navbar coloring links

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, hyperlink, navbar

I am having trouble with my navbar, and been stuck at this for some hours now. 
My navbar looks like this:

```
<div id="pages">
        <?php wp_nav_menu();?>
    </div>
```

Very simple wordpress navbar. Wordpress gives every page on this menu automaticly a class name like .page-item-30 also wordpress gives them all the class .page-item.

What I want to achieve is so when i hover 1 Page the background turns red (#ff0000) and the font-color turns white; My css looks like this

```
#pages li{
display: inline;
float: left;
height: 20px;
padding: 5px;
margin: 0px;
margin-top: -17px;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#pages li:hover{
background-color: #ff0000;
}
/** 
.page-item-27:hover a{
color: white;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.page-item-2:hover a{
color: white;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.page-item-21:hover a {
color: white;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
**/
.page-item:hover a {
color: white;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.current_page_item {
background-color: #ff0000;
}
.current_page_item a{
color: white;
}
```

Now i tried using .page-item-27 or so do define when the font-color has to change but that is very unreliable since it relies on the right ID of the page. So If i have a new page with a ID not in my CSS my navigation doesnt work right.

Is there a way of changing the color of the font?

In my current css there is this

```
.page-item:hover a {
color: white;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

which in my Mind should work, but it doesn't.

If you don't understand it completly under [danielps1.de](http://danielps1.de) you can check out my live-page. Just hover my navigation on the left

Thanks for the help

Comment: If you want to link to a demo (which is very useful) please link to a demo site, such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, otherwise as soon as you correct your problem the link, showing the problem, *ceases to show the problem*. Also, can you show the relevant HTML that you want to style, which makes the problem far more clear to us.

Comment: Will do in the future, But it is pretty complicated integrating wordpress into jsFiddle and If I can't use the wordpress functions I will miss a lot of content, which has the problem in it.

Comment: As does the HTML that the browser sees, otherwise your css wouldn't work without preprocessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is just a little mistake.

Your CSS selector should be:

```
.page_item a:hover{
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Instead of:

```
.page-item:hover a {
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks! I was sure i tried that one already but okay.. i guess I didn't it works!

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
li.page_item a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

as the CSS selector!

Comment: yeah works too, thanks. li isn't 100% needed though.